# In PowerShell, how can I have the "DDD" strings that *might* include special characters returned to me that contain "DDD"

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, and using a data file named **SOF.txt**, how can I have the **DDD** strings that *might* include "special" characters returned to me that contain **DDD**, but with also having duplicated results removed, and sorting the results in alphabetical order?

The PowerShell version that I am using is: 5.1.15063.1446

EXAMPLE:

**CONTENTS OF SOF.TXT FILE:**

AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG

AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG

BLAHBLAHBLAH

BLAHBLAHBLAH

CCC 111.DDD EEE FFF GGG

CCC 111.DDD EEE FFF GGG

ddd.222 EEE FFF GGG

ddd.222 EEE FFF GGG

AAA BBB CCC DDD.!@#.333 EEE FFF GGG

AAA BBB CCC DDD.!@#.333 EEE FFF GGG

AAA BBB CCC !@#.333.DDD EEE FFF GGG

AAA BBB CCC !@#.333.DDD EEE FFF GGG

BBB CCC SOF.DDD EEE FFF GGG

BBB CCC SOF.DDD EEE FFF GGG

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**

!@#.333.DDD

111.DDD

DDD

DDD.!@#.333

ddd.222

SOF.DDD

Comment: Are you able to show any [mcve] or attempt you've made on your own so far?

Comment: there are very, very few situations that require "one-liner" scripts. most of the time, the "requirement" is simply very bad coding by "l33t" script kiddies. ///// there are **_good_** reasons for one-liners, but they tend to be focused on trading speed to save RAM. ///// so ... why the one-liner requirement?

Comment: I will remove the optional "requirement" requesting a one-liner.  I will also post what I have thus far in a bit.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? There were major changes between v1, v2, and v3, so knowing if you're using one of those versions or something later is helpful.

Comment: PowerShell Version: 5.1.15063.1446

Comment: You've got three working answers; to show that the question has been answered satisfactorily, you should pick the one you like best, and click on the check mark. That "accepts" the answer, lets everyone who reads the question later know that it has been answered satisfactorily, and throws the person who answered it a few points of reputation on the site.

Answer (score 1):

This might give you what you are looking for.

```
Get-Content -Path '.\sof.txt' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.split(' ') } |
    ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match 'DDD') { $_ }} |
    Sort-Object -Unique
```

One-liner style, but not professional to put into a .ps1 script.

```
gc '.\sof.txt'|%{$_.split(' ')}|%{if($_ -match 'DDD'){$_}}|sort -u
```

One-liner style borrowed from @Jeff Zeitlin:

```
(gc .\sof.txt)-split' '|where{$_-match'DDD'}|sort -u
```

Comment: This also works!  Thank you for taking the time to figure this out!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

It so happens that a one-liner will do it:

```
 (Get-Content -Path sof.txt) -split " " | Where-Object { $_ -match "DDD" } | Sort-Object -Unique
```

`(Get-Content sof.txt)` evaluates to an array of the lines in the file. This array is then parsed and further split on spaces (`-split " "`), giving an array of "words", which is in turn piped to `Where-Object` to be matched against "DDD" (case-insensitive) (`{$_ -match "DDD"}`), and those words matching the "DDD" are piped to `Sort-Object`, which then gathers and sorts them and emits only one instance (`-Unique`) of each string it receives.

Comment: This works!  Thank you for taking the time to figure this out!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

this will do the job [*grin*] ...

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG
AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG
BLAHBLAHBLAH
BLAHBLAHBLAH
CCC 111.DDD EEE FFF GGG
CCC 111.DDD EEE FFF GGG
ddd.222 EEE FFF GGG
ddd.222 EEE FFF GGG
AAA BBB CCC DDD.!@#.333 EEE FFF GGG
AAA BBB CCC DDD.!@#.333 EEE FFF GGG
AAA BBB CCC !@#.333.DDD EEE FFF GGG
AAA BBB CCC !@#.333.DDD EEE FFF GGG
BBB CCC SOF.DDD EEE FFF GGG
BBB CCC SOF.DDD EEE FFF GGG
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$Target = 'DDD'

$HasTarget = $InStuff -match $Target
$OnlyTargetSegment = $HasTarget.Split(' ').Where({$_ -match $Target}) |
    Sort-Object -Unique

$OnlyTargetSegment
```

output ...

```
!@#.333.DDD
111.DDD
DDD
DDD.!@#.333
ddd.222
SOF.DDD
```

the 1st `-match` grabs only the lines that match the target. the 2nd `-match` grabs only the segments of the split that contain the target.

Comment: This also works!  Thank you for taking the time to figure this out!  :-)

Comment: @lars312 - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little bit ... [*grin*]